# NameError when copying dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nameerror

I have the following code:

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import sys

def stockchart(symbol):
    data1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Open','High','Low', 'Close','Volume']) #Added this line
    ts = TimeSeries(key='1ORS1XLM1YK1GK9Y', output_format='pandas')
    data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol=symbol, interval='1min', outputsize='full')
    data = data.rename(columns={'1. open':'Open','2. high': 'High','3. low': 'Low', '4. close':'Close', '5. volume': 'Volume'})
    data.to_csv('stockdata', sep= ' ')
    data1 = data1.append(data)

symbol=input("Enter symbol name:") 
stockchart(symbol)
```

When i run this code i get the following error: `NameError: name 'data1' is not defined`
How can i fix this? What i am trying to do is to get all the data to be put inside data1 dataframe

---

I have added the line which defines data1 I am still getting NameError.
[image]

Comment: `data1` isn't defined anywhere, not sure what you were expecting...

Comment: `date1` is a local variable in `stockchart`, so you can’t access it outside of that scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Open','High','Low', 'Close','Volume'])
```

This will define your dataframe.